# aws policy not attaching ebs volumes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Please help me to verify if my policy is correct as I am unable to available attach EBS volume using this policy?

There is no error so the only possibility is my policy may be not correct?

Any advice or suggestion.In my case there are multiple EBS instances which I am trying to add through loop so could be that possibility as well but before checking that part, I need to be sure that there should not be an issue with policy part.

```
ec2-attach-volume --instance-id "$instanceId" --volume-id "$volumeid"  --device xvdb
```

```html
 InstanceRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Join 
        - '-'
        - - !Ref Product
          - !Ref Environment
          - !Ref EnvironmentNo
          - role
          - docker
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ec2.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'              
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: S3Download
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 's3:GetObject'
                  - ec2:AttachVolume
                  - ec2:DetachVolume
                  - ec2:DescribeInstanceAttribute
                  - ec2:DescribeInstances
                  - ec2:DescribeInternetGateways
                  - ec2:DescribeKeyPairs
                  - ec2:DescribeNetworkAcls
                  - ec2:DescribePlacementGroups
                  - ec2:DescribeRegions
                  - ec2:DescribeRouteTables
                  - ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups
                  - ec2:DescribeSnapshotAttribute
                  - ec2:DescribeSnapshots
                  - ec2:DescribeSpotDatafeedSubscription
                  - ec2:DescribeSpotInstanceRequests
                  - ec2:DescribeSpotPriceHistory
                  - ec2:DescribeSubnets
                  - ec2:DescribeTags
                  - ec2:DescribeVolumes
                  - ec2:DescribeVpcs
                  - ec2:DescribeVpnConnections
                  - ec2:DescribeVpnGateways
                  - ec2:GetConsoleOutput
                  - ec2:StartInstances
                  - ec2:RunInstances
                  - ec2:StopInstances
                  - ec2:UnmonitorInstances
                  - ec2:DescribeAddresses               
                Resource: "*"
  InstanceProfile:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile'
    Properties:
      Roles:
        - !Ref InstanceRole
```

Comment: Side-note: These days it is recommended to use the unified [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) rather than the individual commands.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct policy if someone wants to use it !!!